# Symfony Admin generator: transform batch actions from select list to links

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

in the objects list generated with the admin generator, the batch Action are shown in a select  with a submit button.
I want to transform it and get only link (for example i have the action delete and i want to have a link to delete instead of choosingthe action and than click on the button.)

i have the **_list_batch_actions.php** file but i could'nt see how to get the href for the  tag:

```
    <li class="sf_admin_batch_actions_choice">
    <a href="<?php // url_for('@route')?>"> test</a> // this is what i added but not woorking
  <select name="batch_action">
    <option value=""><?php echo __('Choose an action', array(), 'sf_admin') ?></option>
    <option value="batchDelete"><?php echo __('Delete', array(), 'sf_admin') ?></option>
  </select>
  <?php $form = new BaseForm(); if ($form->isCSRFProtected()): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $form->getCSRFFieldName() ?>" value="<?php echo $form->getCSRFToken() ?>" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  <input type="submit" value="<?php echo __('go', array(), 'sf_admin') ?>" />
</li>
```

Any idea on how i can use it ?

Comment: i don't see how can I refer to the objects beeing selected neither the write action to call !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution one:**

The batch actions are submitted by form by default. You can rewrite the template to put links instead of a form.

Check your auto generated controler in the cache
 *(you need before to see your admin page in order to generate the cache)*.

```
apps/backend/dev/modules/autoYourModule/actions/action.class.php
```

You will find a function `executeBatch()`.

You can copy this function and put it in your admin module controler and then modify its behaviour in order to do what you need.

**Solution two:**

Use javascript to hide your form and put a link which will select the delete action in your select box, the submit the form using javascript.